# App closing automatically on button click from main activity

Tags: java, android

My application is automatically closed when I open activity from button of main activity.But All other activities are working fine.
Here is my code :

```
public class TotalPaymentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tvPaidTotal;
List<CustomerAccount> arr = new ArrayList<>();
AppDatabase appDatabase;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_total_payment);
    initializeAll();


}

private void initializeAll() {

    tvPaidTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPaidTotal);
    new getTotalPayment().execute();

}


public class getTotalPayment extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{

    
    double sum=0;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        arr = appDatabase.CustomerAccountDao().loadAllCustomerAccounts();
        for (int i=0;i<arr.size();i++)
        {
            sum+=arr.get(i).getCreditAmount();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        try {
            tvPaidTotal.setText("Total Amount is :  " + String.valueOf(sum));
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ignored)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

}

And this my button from i call this activity:

```
 case R.id.btnTotalCash: startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,TotalPaymentActivity.class));
```

Note: Activity is created in manifest file.
I searched for solution many websites including stackoverflow but i did not succeed.
Please help me regarding this.
Thanks

Comment: What are you seeing in LogCat when pressing the button? When you say that the application is closed, you mean crashes?

Comment: Yes it crashed when I click on button

Comment: And this logcat on button clicking :2021-08-18 00:13:13.870 20403-20403/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2021-08-18 00:13:13.871 20403-20403/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2021-08-18 00:13:13.913 20403-20403/? E/ample.smaartev: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-08-18 00:13:18.937 20403-20403/com.example.smaartevo E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.serialno"

Comment: @tomerpacific Is there anything else that i can provide?

Comment: Please add the full crash log to the question.

Comment: search for a FATAL followed by a stacktrace in your logcat

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize AppDatabase, like so:

```
public class TotalPaymentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tvPaidTotal;
List<CustomerAccount> arr = new ArrayList<>();
AppDatabase appDatabase;

private final Context context = TotalPaymentActivity.this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_total_payment);
    initializeAll();


}

private void initializeAll() {

    tvPaidTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPaidTotal);
    new getTotalPayment().execute();

}


public class getTotalPayment extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    
    double sum=0;
    
    appDatabase = AppDatabase.getInstance(context);

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        arr = appDatabase.CustomerAccountDao().loadAllCustomerAccounts();
        for (int i=0;i<arr.size();i++)
        {
            sum+=arr.get(i).getCreditAmount();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        try {
            tvPaidTotal.setText("Total Amount is :  " + String.valueOf(sum));
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ignored)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with the help of my friend. I forgot to initialize the Appdatabase. Here is solution line :

```
appDatabase = AppDatabase.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
```